# How to bind web service in AngularJs?

Tags: php, angularjs, webserver

I am new to AngularJS. I created a AngularJs App like below

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="phonecatApp">
    <head>       
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    Search: <input ng-model="query">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <ul class="phones">
                        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones| filter:query">
                            {{phone.name}}
                            <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body> </html>
```

and Js :

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
        'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOMâ„¢ with Wi-Fi',
        'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOMâ„¢',
        'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
];
```

});

This is simple example of data binding , but I want get JSON data from my web service `localhost/product.php` and bind it in HTML. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Just assign the JSON data coming from your web server to `$scope.phones` in its `success` handler

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution ,

JS CODE :

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://localhost/google/cibl/dashboard/get_all_user').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.greeting = data;
    });
```

}

and HTML binding :

```
        <div ng-app="" ng-controller="Hello">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in greeting">
                    {{ x.user_name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and its working properly .